# Sql delete same row and 1 with delimiter

Tags: php, mysql

I can't find a appropriate solution to delete multiple row in sql table with a delimiter. Here is a example of this problem:

```
id  token 
1]  c85456d5352a522a
2]  c85456d5352a522a_133_aaa
3]  c85456d5352a522a_133_aaa_203_bbb
```

If original token is same from beginning with same start token, I need to delete all of them.

I have no idea what is the best way.

I have tested with explode but i don't know how i can compare with modified token?

http://codepad.org/FZ29mC15

```
$orginal        = '4d4ff15544cdad8b';
$modified_token = '4d4ff15544cdad8b_7176_con_8009_con';
$test           = explode('_',$modified_token);
$result         = $test[0];

//I know, It's not logic now but i try...
if($orginal == $result){
    //Sql Delete request here
    echo 'Delete: '.$result;
}
```

What is the good way to compare original and explode token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LIKE` to match a pattern beginning with the token. Since `_` is a wildcard that matches any character, you need to escape it.

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE token = '4d4ff15544cdad8b'
OR token LIKE '4d4ff15544cdad8b\_%'
```

Comment: That's exactly the best way, thank you for this explaination and this example.